# Token Verfication from Single Device

Tags: security, mobile, token

I am new to tokens and cookies in general, and it seems to me that the security risks seem pretty great. I have done some research on tokens, and it seems I will need to use them as part of a mobile application, however.

My question is, can you generate a hash/token based on the user's device name or some other datum/data that is/are unique to the user's mobile device. For example, is it possible to access the IMEI number (probably a bad example) for Android and then generate a hash based on that? (Then, one could simply regenerate the hash inside the software and then if the hashes are not the same, the token/hash would not be valid.)

I read a little about Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF), but it didn't seem very full-proof. Does anyone have any way to combat forgery for tokens (some references and reading would be nice) or have any random ideas that they just happen to be thinking about?

Essentially, what my question boils down to is... is there a way to generate a token yet have it be valid from *only* one device and prevent forgery?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad idea for several reasons:

1) It leaves you open for session fixation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation) and session re-use attacks

2) The token can not be changed in case a session is compromised, meaning that a user can not restore safety to their account if they are ever hacked

3) IMEIs are not fully random. Their entropy is comparatively low. An attacker can thus simply generate random IMEIs, hash them and use them to authenticate against your service to gain access to user's accounts in a brute force attacks.

**Authentication should always be done with something the user knows, not something he/she is.**

So authenticate with a regular username/password combination and then store a strong session ID (e.g. 256 bits) for the duration of the session.

Comment: Ok, so if you store only for the duration of the session then do you have to store the username and password (encrypted somehow I would guess) if you wanted them to be able to log onto the app without having to type their username and password every time?

Comment: No, then you store the session for a longer duration and make it persist between restarts. Never ever store the user's password.

Comment: Then how do mobile applications store peoples' passwords? For example, how does Gmail log me in after I reboot my phone or other mobile device?

Comment: Depends on the application. Some applications will indeed store the password (again, horrible idea from a security perspective, but occasionally necessary for certain protocols). Most will store your session ID in a persistent store (e.g. a file). You reboot your phone, restart the app, the session ID is read and the session is resumed.

Comment: Hm. So then what happens if someone guesses your session id and places that file on a their device? Does the server know your ip address or something that might remain more stable? Do you just assume that the session id might not be valid and make it so that in order to change the password, you need the enter the old password and don't make it easy to modify settings (or whatever...)?

Comment: When someone guesses the session ID, your session can be hijacked. This is a real problem in MITM attacks, etc. It is also why the ID should only be sent over HTTPS and be sufficiently long. Binding to IP is a bad idea, as modern users tend to quickly change IPs. Think mobile networks and Wifi. But we're getting into too many details. If this information is new to you, I highly recommend you read up on the core concepts of authentication, authorisation and session management. They fill books and can't be explained in SO comments.